# Unknown type name 'instancetype' - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two Xcode projects on my computer. Each of them has a declaration with return type 'instancetype', but somehow one project can compile while another is showing error: Unknow type name 'instancetype'.

I tried to find the reason by comparing two projects' build settings, but even everything is set to the same, the problem still not solved.

My projects are using Apple LLVM7.0, which I think already supports 'instancetype'. please tell me what are the potential causes of this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: It seems I have incorrectly used 'instancetype' in a declaration like: `instancetype methodA(args...)`, without a `+` or `@interface`.